# SonarQube Typescript dependency error in Jenkins

Tags: node.js, typescript, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Our UI is written on JS using Typescript and builds by 'npm run build ....'
I'm trying to add SonarQube analysis, but it fails on Typescript check with error:

```
ERROR: Cannot find module 'typescript'
ERROR: TypeScript dependency was not found and it is required for analysis.
ERROR: Install TypeScript in the project directory or use NODE_PATH env. variable to set TypeScript location, if it's located outside of project directory.
ERROR: Missing TypeScript dependency
```

Here is my Jenkinsfile:

```
nodejs(nodeJSInstallationName: 'NodeJS') {
                env.NODEJS_HOME = "${tool 'NodeJS'}"
                def scannerHome = tool "sonar"
                withSonarQubeEnv('sonar'){
                    sh """
                        ${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner \
                            -Dsonar.projectKey=project-name-${BUILD_ENV} \
                            -Dsonar.sources=src
                    """
                }
            }
```

But every time I'm running this stage, I'm receiving output with error mentioned above. Please see full output:

```
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /home/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/sonar/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarScanner 4.3.0.2102
INFO: Java 1.8.0_162 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 5.3.0-1017-aws amd64
INFO: User cache: /home/jenkins/.sonar/cache
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /home/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/sonar/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 8.1.0
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
WARN: SonarScanner will require Java 11 to run starting in SonarQube 8.x
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=546ms
INFO: Server id: *********
INFO: User cache: /home/jenkins/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load/download plugins
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=122ms
INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=160ms
WARN: Plugin SonarQube CNES Report [cnesreport] uses a child first classloader which is deprecated
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Process project properties (done) | time=12ms
INFO: Execute project builders
INFO: Execute project builders (done) | time=12ms
INFO: Project key: project-name
INFO: Base dir: /home/jenkins/workspace/project-name
INFO: Working dir: /home/jenkins/workspace/project-name/.scannerwork
INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'project-name'
INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'project-name' (done) | time=104ms
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=143ms
INFO: Detected Jenkins
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=2245ms
INFO: Indexing files...
INFO: Project configuration:
INFO: Load project repositories
INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=104ms
INFO: 7 files indexed
INFO: 0 files ignored because of scm ignore settings
INFO: Quality profile for css: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for js: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for ts: Sonar way
INFO: ------------- Run sensors on module project-name
INFO: Load metrics repository
INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=108ms
INFO: Sensor SonarCSS Metrics [cssfamily]
INFO: Sensor SonarCSS Metrics [cssfamily] (done) | time=32ms
INFO: Sensor SonarCSS Rules [cssfamily]
INFO: 1 source files to be analyzed
INFO: 1/1 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Sensor SonarCSS Rules [cssfamily] (done) | time=1058ms
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=3ms
INFO: Sensor JavaScript analysis [javascript]
INFO: TypeScript dependency was not found inside project directory, Node.js will search TypeScript using module resolution algorithm; analysis will fail without TypeScript.
INFO: 5 source files to be analyzed
INFO: 5/5 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Sensor SonarJS [javascript]
INFO: 5 source files to be analyzed
INFO: Sensor SonarJS [javascript] (done) | time=304ms
INFO: 5/5 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Sensor JavaScript analysis [javascript] (done) | time=2296ms
INFO: Sensor TypeScript analysis [javascript]
INFO: Found 1 tsconfig.json file(s): [/home/jenkins/workspace/project-name/tsconfig.json]
ERROR: Cannot find module 'typescript'
ERROR: TypeScript dependency was not found and it is required for analysis.
ERROR: Install TypeScript in the project directory or use NODE_PATH env. variable to set TypeScript location, if it's located outside of project directory.
ERROR: Missing TypeScript dependency
org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.MissingTypeScriptException: Missing TypeScript dependency
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.EslintBridgeServerImpl.loadTsConfig(EslintBridgeServerImpl.java:270)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.TypeScriptSensor.loadTsConfigs(TypeScriptSensor.java:173)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.TypeScriptSensor.analyzeFiles(TypeScriptSensor.java:109)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.AbstractEslintSensor.execute(AbstractEslintSensor.java:107)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.TypeScriptSensor.execute(TypeScriptSensor.java:53)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse(AbstractSensorWrapper.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:85)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:77)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:82)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:386)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:382)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:351)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:141)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:72)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:66)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)

INFO: Sensor TypeScript analysis [javascript] (done) | time=117ms
INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java]
INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java] (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Sensor HTML [web]
INFO: Sensor HTML [web] (done) | time=3ms
INFO: Sensor SonarTS [typescript]
INFO: Since SonarTS v2.0, TypeScript analysis is performed by SonarJS analyzer v6.0 or later. No TypeScript analysis is performed by SonarTS.
INFO: Sensor SonarTS [typescript] (done) | time=0ms
INFO: ------------- Run sensors on project
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=8ms
INFO: CPD Executor 3 files had no CPD blocks
INFO: CPD Executor Calculating CPD for 2 files
INFO: CPD Executor CPD calculation finished (done) | time=10ms
INFO: Analysis report generated in 119ms, dir size=91 KB
INFO: Analysis report compressed in 34ms, zip size=22 KB
INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 222ms
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse https://******
INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
INFO: More about the report processing at https://********
INFO: Analysis total time: 10.225 s
```

I tried to add typescript as Global npm packages to install in Global tool configuration, tried to install it via Jenkinsfile (`sh "npm install -g typescript"`), tried to manually add its installation path to my NODE_PATH and PATH environment variables, but without any success.

Could anyone help me with it, as I don't know what else I can do?

P.S. Installing NodeJS and Typescript on slave instance will not work, as Jenkins has a lot of slaves and many of them automatically start, stop, spin up etc.

Comment: Hi there, did you find a solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

Was solved by moving the SonarQube analysis step in Jenkins to be after the build step, which comprises of `npm install` and `npm run build`.